# JS change input value

Tags: javascript, html, web

My problem is:
I have two input boxes one for a code and one for a price:

```
<input class="style" name="code" id="code" type="text">
<input class="style" name="price" id= "price" type="text" value="&euro; 15,00" readonly="readonly">
```

Now i want to change the price by code (like a check from a code array [code1][code2]. result to code1 = price/2 and code2 = price/4 ) This i want to check by a script in real time or befor the post (on submit). This this possible when yes how? Or is there another better way to do this ?

I have:

```
while(true) 
{
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;

    var codes = new Array("promo1", "promo2");

    for (var i=0; i<codes.length; i++) {

        if (codes[i] == code) {
            document.getElementById("price").value = "5";
        }       
    }
}
```

and my input fields are obviously in a form-field
but the value doesnt change, but why ? 
I dont have to change in real time it would be ok if the post sends the new value...any solutions/better ideas/hints ?
I know there is JQuery a better approach but it shouldn't be a problem with js.

fiddle link:
[jsfiddle.net/vicR/4Mtbr](http://jsfiddle.net/vicR/4Mtbr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be obtained easily in many ways, specially if one takes use of libraries or frameworks, but with pure javascript it should be done as so:

```
while(true) {
 var code = document.getElementById("code").value
 //now check for valid code in some sort of map or array
 //REMEMBER javascript supports string indexed arrays such as arr["#45"]
 if(code == validatorFunctionOrCode) { //obviously pseudo
  document.getElementById("price").value = "your corresponding price to the code"
 }
}
```

- This is all checked dynamically and before you hit the submit button.

With this said I would strongly recommend [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org) since it supports databinding (example - [databinding](http://www.egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-binding) )

Comment: is it okay to just implement the script into the header or is into an external .js file better (elegant)?

Comment: hmm.. i cannot get it to work. im kind of a js newbie. i'm having my conditions and implement it into my body. but no changes at all

Comment: i meant header. sorry.

Comment: 1. Generally one it's more elegant to have the script in a different file. But when websites launch their sites they tend to "minimize" their html, css and js in a huge file so that the client doesn't hafto make multiple requests to the backend. 

2. Could you give me a code dump on fiddle or such? it's easier to review.

Answer (score 1):

It is done with some jQuery code:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    $('#price').val(value_you_want_to_change);
});
```

Comment: this should change the value to `value_you_want_to_change` after submit or?!

Comment: the value changed before submit